# Trying to get a template to work for an element of a struct in c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

This is my first time using templates. I use the template only for an element of the struct.

```
    using namespace std;
    namespace lulz{

    template<typename T>
    struct Contacto {
    string Cname;
    string Apellidos;
    string NumTel;
    string email;
    T sexo;
    Contacto *Proximo;
    };
    typedef Contacto* ContactPtr;


    class Lista {
    public:
    Lista();
    ~Lista();
    bool ContactoVacio(ContactPtr Contact1);  
    void InsertContact(ContactPtr& Contact1, Contacto Temp); 
    void BuscarContact(ContactPtr Contact1, string Name, string Lastname);
    void Display(ContactPtr Contact1);
    void Deletes(ContactPtr Contact1);

    ContactPtr Cabeza;
    };
```

I'm templating the struct, but unsure if should do the same for the class. I don't call the element as a parameter in any of the functions so I'd guess not. I access the struct by the typedef.

```
    using namespace std;
    using namespace lulz;

    int main(){

    Lista cabezalista;
    Contacto Temp;
    ContactPtr Cabeza;
    string name, lastname;
    int Choice;
    ifstream entrada;
    Opening(entrada);

    Contacto<string> sexo;

    while(!entrada.eof())
    {
    entrada >> Temp;
    cabezalista.InsertContact(Cabeza,Temp);
    }
```

In file included from main.cpp:1:
Proyecto.h:27: error: expected initializer before '*' token
Proyecto.h:35: error: 'ContactPtr' has not been declared
Proyecto.h:37: error: 'ContactPtr' has not been declared
Proyecto.h:37: error: 'Contacto' is not a type
Proyecto.h:40: error: 'ContactPtr' has not been declared
Proyecto.h:42: error: 'ContactPtr' has not been declared
Proyecto.h:44: error: 'ContactPtr' has not been declared
Proyecto.h:47: error: 'ContactPtr' does not name a type
Proyecto.h:52: error: 'Contacto' is not a type
Proyecto.h:54: error: missing template arguments before 'Temp'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm templating the struct, but unsure if should do the same for the class.

The answer is, "most likely yes".

Your hope of being able to use

```
typedef Contacto* ContactPtr;
```

to avoid making `Lista` a class template is based on incomplete understanding of how templates work. The above is not valid C++ code, as your compiler has pointed out.

`Contact` is a class template, not a class. Hence you cannot create a `typedef` for `Contact*`. You can use:

```
template <typename T>
using ContactPtr = Contacto<T>*;
```

But then, you will have to use `ContactPtr<T>` where `T` is a valid type.

In order to be able to use `Contact` or `ContactPtr` in `Lista`, you will need a template parameter. The template parameter could be hard coded to a known type or you can make `Lista` a class template. In the latter case, you can use the template parameter of `Lista` for using `Contacto` or `ContactPtr`.

```
template <typename T>
class Lista
{
   ...
   Contacto<T>* Cabeza;
};
```

or

```
template <typename T>
class Lista
{
   ...
   ContactPtr<T> Cabeza;
};
```